# Why does [rounded rectangle] cause random "divide by zero" PGF Math Error?

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, pgfmath, tikzmark, tikz-shape

I was using `tikzmark` to insert `tikz` drawings inside an equation when I encountered a weird bug, which I reduced to the following minimal (non-)working example:

---

The following file `bug.tex`,

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}

\begin{document}

\tikz[remember picture]{\node (a) {a};}
\tikz[remember picture]{\node[rounded rectangle] (c) {c};}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \draw (a) -- (c);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

when compiled, triggers the following error:

```
! Package PGF Math Error: You asked me to calculate `1/0.0', but I cannot divid
e any number by zero.

See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.14   \draw (a) -- (c)
                       ;
```

This error does not appear if you do any of these:

- remove `[rounded rectangle]`
- remove the `\draw` command
- `\draw (c) -- (a);` instead of `(a) -- (c)`
- change randomly the content of the nodes, for instance:

  - if you change the content of `(a)` to `{b}`, it works
  - if you change the content of `(c)` to `{b}`, it works
  - if you change the contents of both `(a)` *and* `(c)` to `{b}`, it does not work.

---

Two more remarks:

- The `[remember picture, overlay]` does not seem to be the source of the problem: the error still appears when I remove it. I keep it in the MWE because when this bug does not interrupt the compilation chain, removing it causes other problems later on.
- If you change one of the elements I mentioned above to make it compile, and then undo this change and recompile it without removing the `.aux` file, it may compile without a problem.

---

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong? What exactly is the reason for this behavior?

Comment: My suspicion is that the coordinates you eventually draw between end up being at the same place, or at least at the same height, and this causes a problem somewhere, possibly in the bounding box calculation.  This would fit with the fact that changing the height of one node removes the problem.  I can't experiment right now so am leaving this as a comment in case it is helpful to anyone investigating.

Comment: By trying to fix it by going back to a more primitive form of \tikzmark, I was able to reproduce the bug without the tikzmark library, which is therefore in the clear.

Comment: Can you please open a bug report with this MWE on https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf?  Of course this example doesn't produce anything meaningful during the first run but it should not throw an error, so that's a bug.  I'm already tracing it and for some reason the transformation matrix in `(a)--(c)` is `{0.0}{0.0}{-1.01932}{0.0}{0pt}{0pt}` which is complete bullshit.

Comment: Gladly. There: https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/908.

Answer (score 4):

Inside a tikz node, use `\subnode` provided by `tikzmark`, instead of `\tikzmarknode`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark, shapes.misc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
  \node {\subnode{a}{a} \subnode[rounded rectangle]{c}{c}};
  \draw (a) -- (c);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That is a good point. At the time of this answer, the `\tikzmarknode`s of my MWE were in such a `\node`. That was not necessary to the bug and I removed this useless `\node`. By the way, the reason I am in fact using `\tikzmarknode` inside some `\node`, instead of `\subnode`, is because I want to pass them the `[state]` option, from tikz library `automata`. And this is an option to which `\subnode` is not sensible.

Comment: Just as a suggestion on the issue of drawing a subnode, draw a second node afterwards using the `fit` library to fit it to the subnode.  This keeps the drawing commands out of the original node's contents.

Comment: Yes, thank you @AndrewStacey, I read that in the tikzmark manual. ;-) But I find that writing two commands and creating two nodes for each node or state of automaton that I want to create reduces the readability or reusability of the code.